# How to read data from xlxs file when it contains duplicates

Tags: java, apache-poi

My xl file looks like this:

```
Name         2 - High     3 - Medium    4 - Low         Grand Total

Shankarnag  1           

Shankarnag         1        

Padmarubhan     1       

Padmarubhan     1       

Shankarnag  1
```

I want to calculate each name and their value.

For example:

```
 Name        2 - High     3 - Medium    4 - Low         Grand Total
 Shankarnag     2               1                           3
 Padmarubhan    2
```

Can anyone please help explain how to do that?

Comment: Can you please correct your table formatting? The numbers are all over the place, unless that is the intent...

Comment: Without the code you've written, it's very hard for us to tell you what you're doing wrong! Format your table properly, post the code you have so far, and we might be able to assist